# MYSQL"list of employees from second largest department" not by subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I have one scenario where I need to list all the employees from the second largest department. (1 Employee belongs to one department only).
I can get the results using following subquery:

```
SELECT empno,ename,deptno 
FROM emp 
WHERE deptno = (
                 SELECT deptno 
                 FROM emp 
                 GROUP BY deptno 
                 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1,1
               )
```

But, what if I want to get the same result using JOINs. How can I do that ?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ?? `TOP` is a SQL server syntax and does not work in MySQL

Comment: Thanks Madhur. Have edit the question. Its mysql.

Comment: Dont use ALL CAPS. is consider as SHOUTING and is rude

Comment: Ok Sure. Thanks Juan. Will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do the following, using `JOIN` on a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html):

```
SELECT empno,ename,deptno
FROM emp AS t1 
JOIN (SELECT t2.deptno 
      FROM emp AS t2 
      GROUP BY t2.deptno 
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
      LIMIT 1,1
     ) AS t3 ON t3.deptno = t1.deptno
```

Comment: Thanks Madhur. But this also look like a subquery. My mysql knowledge is weak. So I am not sure. Can you explain.

Comment: @user3910197 It is kind of a subquery, but it will be efficient, as it will be computed only once. Please read up on the `Derived Tables` link given in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. Can we use 'having' and not use sub query() in any place in the logic.

Comment: Well I would also fail that test because I also consider this a Subquery. But as Madhur said this is a Derived Table.

Comment: @user3910197 to use Having, you will have to group by on `deptno`. That would mean, you wont get employees as different rows. if you want all the employee names as comma separated in a single string, then using group_concat and having it can be done

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza At the end of the day, all are subqueries, be it derived table, correlated subqueries, using exists clause etc. But difference will be in how MySQL uses them. In a derived table, this particular subquery will be run only once. However in the OP's approach, I have a strong sense that it would run for every row

Comment: Thanks Madhur for help.

Comment: Any decent optimizer would calculate the subquery only once. My guess is the performance should be the same. But a test would be appropiated.